getBoundingClientRect returns an empty object
I'm using Cypress 11.2.0 with Pragmatic DnD library - testing the drag and drop of elements.
In my Cypress test, when using getBoundingClientRect it returns an empty object {}. This should be returning data including the x and y co-ordinates of the element. Any idea how to get the co-ordinates of an element in Cypress?
cy.get('[data-test="drag-handle"]')
  .first()
  .then(($target) => {
    let coordsDrop = $target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    cy.log('coordsDrop', coordsDrop);
  })


There is no way an element returns an empty bounding client rect, you just need to look a bit harder.
For example.com:
cy.visit('https://example.com');

cy.get('h1')
  .first()
  .then(($target) => {
    let coordsDrop = $target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    cy.log('coordsDrop', coordsDrop);
    console.log('coordsDrop', coordsDrop);
  })

The log:

Click the log entry:

or use consolg.log(coords)

